# How to automatically run a script in chrome console

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to run a chrome console command whenever I land on a webpage. What recourses should I look at to go about doing that? This is all I want to run on loop:
`document.querySelector("#currentKey").innerText`

Result should be something like this:

```
V&2Y/9);fQpeP"X,
W{8Q]^DdQB>+>A5z
_Am[{.`>j^8b/DD5
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to official google documentation

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/snippets/